# Why are my CGPoints all returning as {0,0}?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgpoint

I am trying to store the locations of 10 UIImages I have stored within a UICollection and placed using the interface builder. I am trying to do so using View.center but all my CGPoints are returning as {0,0} when logged.

Another strange thing is I set up a break point on the for loop, two {0,0} values are returning prior to the loop beginning.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    dealerBtnOrigins = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSValue *point;
        CGPoint cGPoint;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cGPoint = ((UIImageView *)[dealerBtns objectAtIndex:i]).center;
            point = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:((UIImageView *)[dealerBtns objectAtIndex:i]).center];
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(cGPoint));
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point.CGPointValue));
            [dealerBtnOrigins addObject:point];
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible the interface builder has yet to place each UIImage within its correct location prior to viewDidLoad finishing?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (`CGPoint CGPoint;` and `CGPoint = ((UIImageView...`). Please post the code that you are actually using. Also what does `[dealerBtns objectAtIndex:i]` return?

Comment: @Sebastian This is the code I'm using and it compiles fine. I'll repaste it just to be sure. [dealerBtns objectAtIndex:i] Returns a UIImage.

Comment: Yup it works, I'll rename CGPoint to cGPoint to avoid any confusion.

Comment: You're right, it works. But please give your variable a name different from the type...

Comment: Where are you testing this? You need to be testing at least on viewWillAppear or later if it's designed in IB

Comment: viewDidLoad, I'll throw it in to viewWillAppear see how it goes.

Comment: Your UICollection hasn't rendered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collectionView hasn't rendered yet in viewDidLoad. Place the code in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear after you have created the collectionView for the coors to show.